# MS Excel: Using AGGREGATE to add up all mileage in each month

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have the following data in a logbook format:

```
DATE           MILEAGE
02-Jul-13         15
05-Jul-13         12
09-Jul-13         156
10-Aug-13         20
11-Aug-13         20
12-Aug-13         232
12-Aug-13         20
13-Aug-13         265
15-Aug-13         20
18-Aug-13         20
```

I am looking to extract data from it.

I need to ignore errors and #N/A so I have been trying to use the AGGREGATE function. To no avail though.

I would like to present the following information:

Mileage this month -

```
=AGGREGATE(9,7, IF(MONTH(IFERROR(LogBookTable[Date], 0)) = MONTH(TODAY()), LogBookTable[Total KM], 0))    - Does not work
```

Mileage in July -

```
=AGGREGATE(9,7, IF(MONTH(IFERROR(LogBookTable[Date], 0)) = MONTH(7), LogBookTable[Total KM], 0))    - Does not work
```

Mileage in August -

```
=AGGREGATE(9,7, IF(MONTH(IFERROR(LogBookTable[Date], 0)) = MONTH(8), LogBookTable[Total KM], 0))    - Does not work
```

Total Mileage -

```
=AGGREGATE(9,7,LogBookTable[Total KM])  - This works
```

The monthly mileage and current month mileage all result in a "#VALUE!" being displayed.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Just in case anyone asks, the naming schemes are corrected, it's not the references that aren't working, it's the values.

Comment: Where do you have errors, in Date column, Mileage column or both?

Answer (score 1):

You could use DSUM. If you had two criteria cells setup Say in D1:E2 as follows:

```
    Date    Date
>1/07/2013  <31/7/2013
```

and if your data was in A1:B11 (as per your example above), to return a sum for July ignoring errors, use the following formula:

```
=DSUM(A1:B11,2,D1:E2)
```

You could setup the criteria such that they were updated based on the current month, and that the month end is calculated using:

```
="<"& DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,DAY(1)-1)
```

and the month start calculated by:

```
=">"& DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(1))
```

Remember that with criteria, multiple criteria on the same row is an AND, and multiple rows on the same criteria is an OR.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMIF` is you add a column representing the month of the date:

[image]

Column B contains `=MONTH` of Column A. All you have to do is update the DATE entry in A16 with a new date. B16 is accordingly updated with the appropriate month, creating a new monthly aggregate/sum.